# c# application Installation problem in the assembly

Tags: c#

I published my app in Visual Studio 2008.
I'm getting a problem installing on another PC(this PC dont have .net).
During the install, the following error appears:

"Unable to run or install the application. The application requires that
assembly stdole version 7.0.3300.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)
first."

plz help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to install a .NET program on another PC, you have to install the same version of the **.NET framework** as your are targeting with your program first. (With visual studio 2008 that is probably 3.5)

Also, make sure you deploy the assembly for stdole in your installation package.

Comment: And you'll need to be sure it's the right version of the Framework.  (That should be obvious, but I thought I should say it.)